# How would you reverse what this code does?

Tags: java, eclipse, encryption

Here is the code I have for an encryption class:

```
String encrypt;
String message;
String alpha;
String eMessage;
int index;
Key keyObject;

public String Encrypt(){

        String[] alphabet = {
                "a" , "b" , "c" , "d" , "e" , "f" , "g" , "h" , "i" , "j" , "k" , "l" , "m" , 
                "n" , "o" , "p" , "q" , "r" , "s" , "t" , "u" , "v" , "w" , "x" , "y" , "z"

            };

        StringBuilder sbAlphabet = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder sbEncrypt = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i <= 25; i++) {
            sbAlphabet.append(alphabet[i]);
        }
        alpha = sbAlphabet.toString();
        message = message.toLowerCase();
        for(int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++) {
            index = alpha.indexOf(message.charAt(i));
            sbEncrypt.append(keyObject.key.charAt(index));
        }
        return sbEncrypt.toString();
    }
}
```

Right now this code goes through the alphabet string and then encrypts a message that the user inputs into a string from a randomly generated key in a different class. What I'm trying to figure out is how would i do the opposite of this? If I want to decrypt a message instead of encrypting it, (like if user enters an encoded message and then enters the same key used to encrypt it), I want it to display the users input decoded. I'm pretty sure the code to do that would be like this code except reversed. Does anyone have any know how to do this?

Comment: You need to reverse the look ups.  Instead of using `alpha`, use `keyObject` to find the index of the character, this then becomes the entry point into `alpha`

Comment: What's with all that code to build `alpha`? Why not just write `alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";`? And why is `alpha` a *field*, and not a *local variable*?

Comment: The question isn't how would we do it, the question is, what have you tried?  Based on loose observation, this is basic substitution encryption, it takes the character from the `messages` and substitutes for a character from the `key` based on the indices between the `alpha` and `key`.  What do you think if you used the `key` as the index look up and the `alpha` as substitution?